# how to pass form action on button click as well as perform some functionality on that button click?

Tags: angularjs, html

i want to perform 2 action on button click

1) is perform save operation and on that success

2)goto paypal

```
<form role="form" id="checkoutform" name="checkoutform" novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="saveClick()" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">

...
...
..
 <button type="submit" id="purchase" class="btn btn-primary">Purchase</button>
</form>
```

using angular js.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to redirect to PayPal **after** you've saved, so my best bet would be to call window.location.href on the success method of your save action

Comment: @Raz0rwire i also pass some hidden inputs like  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="{{checkoutData.payplaConfig.cmd}}">

Comment: In that case, you should probably post your current javascript code too

Comment: $scope.saveClick = function () {

     userService.Save($scope.checkoutData.userinfo).success(function (data, status, headers) {
            toastr.success('User saved successfully!');
            $scope.start();

            $timeout(function () {
              
                angular.element('#checkoutform').triggerHandler('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
            });

        })
       .error(function (data, status, headers) {
           toastr.error(data);
       });


    };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have 2 form in 1 html file then if you want to call another form (2nd) on click of first form button then ...

this is the best solution using angularjs
i created on function in .js file

```
    $scope.load = function () {
              document.getElementById("paypalform").submit();
      }
```

and call it in another function like save()

my first form have 1 button and its call save after that on success of save function i call this one...

```
$timeout(function () { $scope.load(); }, 1000, true);
```

this function calls another form(2nd) which name like paypalform.

and its working..

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question for #1 I believe.

> 1) is perform save operation and on that success

The `ng-click="saveClick()"` directive will fire the `saveClick()` function in your controller.

There you can perform your save operation.

If you don't have your app or controller setup visit AngularJS docs here. [Angular Getting Started](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started)

> 2)goto paypal

For this, checkout out angular injected service `$location`. You can do something like `$location.path("https://www.paypal.com")`

Here is a [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

If you need to hit the link from your controller rather than send the user to the page you'll want to use angulars `$http` injected service.

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: i also pass some hidden inputs like <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="{{checkoutData.payplaConfig.cmd}}"> so how i use window.location='';?

Comment: To "pass" variables to your controller you'll need to use the `ng-model` directive. So `<input ng-model="checkoutData.paypalConfig.cmd">` You can inject window if you like use the `$window` service angular provides. I would take a look at [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to understand binding variables to $scope.

Comment: If you like this answer, please accept it. I would appreciate it.